# How to change Rectanlge Left/Top/Right/Bottom

Tags: c#, .net, gdi

I have two rectangles InnerRectangle and OuterRectangle. I want to verify if four corners of InnerRectangle i.e, Lett, Top, Right, Bottom are completely inside of 
OuterRectangle. If those are outside I want change the ones that are outside. If I change Left/Top/Right/Bottom, how much should I change the width or height? 
Please let me know how to implement this.

```
if (InnerRectangle.Left < OuterRectangle.Left)
{
    // what should I put here
}
if (InnerRectangle.Top < OuterRectangle.Top)
{
    // what should I put here
}
if (InnerRectangle.Right < OuterRectangle.Right)
{
    // what should I put here
}
if (InnerRectangle.Bottom < OuterRectangle.Bottom)
{
    // what should I put here
}
```

Appreciate your help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To check whether rectangle `InnerRectangle` is completely contained inside `OuterRectangle`:**

```
if (OuterRectangle.Contains(InnerRectangle))
{
    // ...
}
```

**To fix `InnerRectangle` so that it is really inside `OuterRectangle`:**

```
InnerRectangle = InnerRectangle.Intersect(OuterRectangle);
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to replace the entire rectangle, just want to change the only corner(s) that is outside. Will this work?

Comment: @Vinjamuri: That’s what this does.